# Entity Framework 6: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image: The Part of the Model that is causing trouble]

So, if you take a look at my model there is a foreign key relationship between POCustomerId in PurchaseOrder and Id in Customer. It is defined in the correct direction, I have changed the name so that it is different than other property names....not that it matters because I reuse property names all over in my model.

And yet, I get the cryptic: "An Item with the same key has already been added" exception whenever I try to load those entities.

If I delete that one relationship with its navigation property the error goes away, so I've zeroed in on that foreign key relationship.

Just for reference, here's the T-sql that defines the PurchaseOrder table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (
[Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[PONumber]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[POCustomerId] INT            NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_PurchaseOrder_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([POCustomerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
```

);

EDIT:

I have been able to get the code to produce the error in two different ways. The first is with the model you see. In a partial class I have the following code that loads all purchase orders for the application:

```
    static PurchaseOrder()
    {
        AllPurchaseOrders = new ObservableCollection<PurchaseOrder>(GroveCreekUtilities.Context.PurchaseOrders);
        AllPurchaseOrders.CollectionChanged += AllPurchaseOrders_CollectionChanged;

        foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in AllPurchaseOrders)
            item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
    }
```

There exception is thrown when the observable collection's constructor is called and entity framework loads the purchase orders.

Since that wasn't working I removed the relationship between puchase orders and customers from the database and just added an observablecollection via a partial class to my purchaseorder class. The strange thing is, when I tried to load that observable collection through the purchase order's work orders first finished product's customer, the same exception throws. In that case there were some interesting things going on. I noticed that the Customer's Id was 0 and that all of its properties were null as if it had not been initialized yet. I can add more code, I'm just not sure what to put.

Comment: Can you show the code that's giving you the error?

Comment: Without seeing your data, I want to say that this is a design issue.  A customer can have 1 or more PO's, and a PO can have 1 or more work orders.  But a customer can also have 1 or more finished products, which in turn have 1 or more work orders.  Couldn't the customer just get to the finished product through the work order and vice-versa?

Comment: you make a good point. it looks like I need to work on my design. The thing about it is I need to associate the finished goods directly to a customer and the POs directly to a customer so they can be created separately. Then I need to be able to add work orders to existing POs.